# How do you handle your custom images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline

I'm creating a rails application which will include several images for different models.
Now I want to organize them and maybe even use rails assets pipeline to add some caching.
I don't think putting the images in the app/assets/images is a good idea ;).
So how should I do it?

I already tried storing my images in a subdirectory of the public directory.
But then I get a routing error like this :

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/links/link.png")
```

Now I'm asking an experts advise. 
Where can I put my images?
Whats your experience? Is it difficult to use the asset pipeline, or is this generally not a good idea? I could also use a CDN but I think this would be overkill for me right now.

Any advise would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think putting images in app/assets/images is not a good idea?

Comment: Because I will also want to upload some images, remove them, ... And I believe assets are precompiled so this wouldn't work for caching right?

Comment: okay, I just ask because you don't tell the reason why. In your case, just stick [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could advice you to use image uploader like Carrierwave or PaperClip . They are created to simplify all the process uploading image in Rails app. Take a look at [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=asciicast). There are a lot of config possibilities about storage - localy , S3 , RackSpace etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a CDN like Amazon S3. If that's overkill then put them in the public/images. Not in the assets folder.

From [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> The asset pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or compress JavaScript and CSS assets.

Your images should already be compressed using png, jpeg or gif.